# How can I have an operation timeout in Portable Class Libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, portable-class-library

I have a portable class library which targets everything. Because of this, there is no Task or async support.. Which is extremely painful.

So, I'm trying to implement a generic extension method so that an operation can timeout. This is what I have so far:

```
    public static bool WithTimeout(Action task, int duration)
    {
        bool complete=false;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                task();
                complete = true;
            });
        int timeout = 0;
        while (!complete)
        {
            new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1);
            timeout++;
            if (timeout > duration)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This seems like its' quite likely though to be wrong and it's very ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: Your code suffers from several portability problems :)  On some targets, it will never see the "completed" bool turn to true.  Declaring it volatile is required.  And you'll almost never get a 1 millisecond wait.  Simply omitting *timeout* and passing *duration* to WaitOne() is the solution.  Having code running beyond the timeout, completely unobserved and potentially blocking for ever is very ugly.

Comment: @HansPassant The problem with that is that if this process completes sooner, I want it to return as soon as it does, not wait for the whole timeout if it's not needed

Comment: Use the MRE the right way, call Set() in the thread instead of using the bool.

Comment: @HansPassant ooooohhhh. That just clicked. Never had to use these things anywhere else. I hate this super strict set of functionality exposed in portable class libraries

Answer (score 3):

@Hans said to use the ManualResetEvent properly. After doing this, I ended up with this (much better) code:

```
    public static bool WithTimeout(Action task, int duration)
    {
        var e=new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                task();
                e.Set();
            });
        return e.WaitOne(duration);
    }
```

Comment: That awkward moment when an edit on your stackoverflow answer exposes a bug in your actual code base

Answer (score 1):

If you want async and task support, I highly suggest looking at the Microsoft BCL library. Its compatible with Portable Class Libraries.

Just search for it with nuget.

http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Comment: I want to, but I can't include any external dependencies :/